# Actors acting the real actors inside a movie?

Tags: film-techniques, supernatural

In the TV show [Supernatural](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460681/), Season 6, Episode 15, Sam and Dean find themselves pushed into an "alternate reality" where they are two *actors* acting in a *TV show* called Supernatural. And their names (in the alternate reality) are Jared Padalecki (Sam) and Jensen Ackles (Dean).

In real world, those two are the two main actors in Supernatural (in our time, our world). Its the same case with Misha Collins (Castiel) and Robert Singer (Producer and Bobby Singer). Also in this *reality*, Genevieve Padalecki is Sam's wife (this is also true in real life- Jared Padalecki is married to Genevieve Padalecki).

Is there any specific name for this kind of technique? The real actors *acting* as themselves in the perspective of their characters?

If there is, are there any specific reasons and work that go into this?

Comment: A C T I N G C E P T I O N

Comment: I guess [*Last Action Hero*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107362/) is a good example, too, with *Arnie*'s movie character *Jack Slater* getting into the real world and meeting the real actor-*Arnie*.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yeah, that's also a good example. In Supernatural also, Dean (the character) becomes Jensen Ackles (who plays Dean). The same happens to a lot of others.

Comment: i found a dozen or so tvtropes *almost* about this -- Actor Allusion and Casting Gag seem near-misses -- but nothing specifically about an actor playing a character that is playing the actor.

Comment: Reminds me of Star Gate SG1 [episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole_X-Treme!) where they meet a bunch of actors on a new tv series based on star gate, another example with a Little twist.

Comment: @Jared [I'm Christian Bocher. I'm portraying the character of Raymond Gunn, who portrays the character of Dr. Levant which is based on the character Daniel Jackson portrayed by the actor, Michael Shanks. Originally portrayed by the actor James Spader, in the feature film.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqlx77c6qj0)

Comment: Wow, quite the jump, quite the shark...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe [Metafiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafiction) is the umbrella term that covers this specific technique, and related ones.  [Metafilm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafilm) being the specific subset that are TV/film works.  They essentially are catch-alls for works that have some sort of self-awareness to them.

[Self-reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reflexive) works would be closer to your specific scenario.  They're works where the work refers to its real-life self.

Comment: @Roshnal "This Is The End" is a good example. :)